# mySQL remote connection through java program

Tags: java, mysql, database, apache, remote-access

I hosted Apache server with xampp and created local MYSQL database on my PC1.

PC1 IS CONNECTED TO NETWORK1.

I developed simple Java program which is connecting to the database this way:

```
static final String USERNAME="[myusername]";
static final String PASSWORD="[password]";
static final String CONN_STRING="jdbc:mysql://[myIP]:3306/[database_name]";

con=DriverManager.getConnection(CONN_STRING , USERNAME, PASSWORD);
```

This is working absolutely fine on my PC1, even though I changed the link with my IP rather than 'localhost'.

It worked after executing this command in database:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO [username]@[myIP] IDENTIFIED BY '[password]' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

So I am trying to do the same with my PC2 which is also storing this JAVA program but it is connected to another network - NETWORK2. Is it possible this to happen - to connect PC2 from external network to mySQL database hosted on PC1 through my JAVA program?

Comment: That GRANT only allows `username` to connect from a single ip `myIP` you will have to allow that `username` to connect from the PC2 ip address or maybe from any ip address

Comment: Hi, yes I added also: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON [database_name].* TO '[username]'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '[password]'

Comment: So is it still failing to connect? And if so please show us the error message(s)

Comment: run:
III 06, 2019 2:20:17 PM javapackage.StartScreen loginBtnActionPerformed
SEVERE: null
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, why not? You just have to make sure that your `PC1` is accessible from the other network and that the necessary ports (`3306`) are open.

You can just ping `PC1` from `PC2` to check if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the `bind-address` from localhost to IP of your mysql server.
Find the mysql conf file and edit:

Location of mysql conf file would be either `/etc/my.cnf`  or `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` or `/usr/local/mysql/etc/my.cnf`

```
bind-address            = <IP address where MySql is running>
```

Also make sure port 3306 from mysql-server machine is open and accessible from other PC. Then add the required privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it through connecting both computers in same LAN connection.After this check ip address of PC on which mysql is installed. You could find out it by simply typing ifconfig(linux)/ipcofing(window) command on terminal. Ensure that your taking local ip address (appears as 192.168.1.144) not public one.

Use that IP address for binding in my /usr/local/mysql/etc/my.cnf file and also use this IP address in your java program. Your code will run successfully.